# Generate a current datestamp in Java

Tags: java, datestamp

What is the best way to generate a current datestamp in Java?

YYYY-MM-DD:hh-mm-ss

Comment: "when not using a database"? What?? Do you normally query a database to retrieve the current time?

Comment: Do you want a String in that format or some sort of timestamp/date object?

Comment: JohnMilikan:  Inefficient tho' 'tis, you can select current date from sysibm.sysdummy1 (that's the DB2 variant, I cna't remember what Oracles dummy tables are called).  You're right though, that's not the way I'd do it.

Comment: I was trying to say that the data I am writing out is not being timestamped for me when I write it into a table. Also I was not wanting to use and Language packs from external vendors.

Thanks very much for your help. I'll also try to be a bit more concise with my questions in future. Cheers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using the standard JDK, you will want to use java.text.SimpleDateFormat

```
Date myDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:HH-mm-ss");
String myDateString = sdf.format(myDate);
```

However, if you have the option to use the Apache Commons Lang package, you can use org.apache.commons.lang.time.FastDateFormat

```
Date myDate = new Date();
FastDateFormat fdf = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd:HH-mm-ss");
String myDateString = fdf.format(myDate);
```

FastDateFormat has the benefit of being thread safe, so you can use a single instance throughout your application. It is strictly for formatting dates and does not support parsing like SimpleDateFormat does in the following example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:HH-mm-ss");
Date yourDate = sdf.parse("2008-09-18:22-03-15");
```

Comment: As of 3.2 FastDateFormat supports parsing :)

Answer (score 8):

```
Date d = new Date();
String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd:HH-mm-ss").format (d);
System.out.println (formatted);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also

```
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

which is what `new Date()` (@[John Millikin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99098/generate-a-current-datestamp-in-java#99105)) uses internally. Once you have that, you can format it however you like.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormatter is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
final DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:hh-mm-ss");

formatter.format(new Date());
```

The [JavaDoc for SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) provides information on date and time pattern strings.